# How to avoid RaceOnRCW when calling the ComboBox Clear function using Invoke

Tags: multithreading, combobox

I am working on a UART terminal program like TeraTerm. I am making my own terminal program since I need some features that I can't find in other terminal programs.

My terminal program can open several terminal windows that each display the output from a chosen COM port. Each terminal window runs in its own thread.

I have overridden the terminal window form's WndProc function to catch device changed events since I want to update a ComboBox's items with the current PC's available COM ports. This is done to keep the list of COM ports up to date if the user is plugging in a USB COM port device.

My WndProc looks as follows:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch(m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_DEVICECHANGE:
                GetAvailableCOMPorts();
                COMPortsComboBox.Invoke(UpdateCOMPortsComboBoxDelegate);
                break;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

The UpdateCOMPortsComboBoxDelegate is the function updating the items in the ComboBox when a device change occurs. It does not matter if the device wa not a COM device. I do not check to keep it simple.

The UpdateCOMPortsComboBox function pointed to by the delegate looks as follows:

```
    private void UpdateCOMPortsComboBox()
    {
        bool State                  = COMPortsComboBox.Enabled;
        COMPortsComboBox.Enabled    = false;           
        COMPortsComboBox.Items.Clear();
        COMPortsComboBox.Enabled    = State;

        // Then add the new list of COM ports
        for(int i = 0; i < AvailableSerialPorts.Length; i++)
        {
            COMPortsComboBox.Items.Add(AvailableSerialPorts[i]);
        }
    }
```

My problems is that I sometimes get a RaceOnRCW at the Clear() method call even though I have used Invoke to make sure it is called on the thread running the controls message loop.

What is going on?

How do I prevent this from happening?

Or maybe how can I figure out if a control is in use on another thread? And then perhaps wait for the other thread to finish.

Is there perhaps a better way to update the ComboBox items with a new list when the device change event occurs?

The call stack looks as follows when it happens:

```
    mscorlib.dll!System.__ComObject.ReleaseSelf() + 0x5 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(object o) + 0x9a bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.StringSource.ReleaseAutoComplete() + 0x11 bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnHandleDestroyed(System.EventArgs e) + 0x85 bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDestroy(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x46 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x44d bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x882 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x13 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x64 bytes 
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DestroyWindow(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWnd) + 0x10 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DestroyHandle() + 0x89 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.DestroyHandle() + 0x157 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.RecreateHandleCore() + 0x16a bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.RecreateHandleCore() + 0x1a bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SetAutoComplete(bool reset, bool recreate) + 0x105 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.ClearInternal() + 0xa1 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Clear() + 0x17 bytes    
>   Echo.exe!Echo.Echo.UpdateCOMPortsComboBox() Line 231 + 0x1d bytes   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x77 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme) + 0xa7 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(object obj) + 0x90 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme) + 0xa2 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks() + 0xda bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control caller, System.Delegate method, object[] args, bool synchronous) + 0x365 bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate method, object[] args) + 0x50 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate method) + 0x7 bytes    
    Echo.exe!Echo.Echo.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 247 + 0x19 bytes    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x13 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x64 bytes 
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.StringSource.Bind(System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef edit, int options) + 0x46 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SetAutoComplete(bool reset, bool recreate) + 0x2f4 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.Add(object item) + 0x55 bytes   
    Echo.exe!Echo.Echo.UpdateCOMPortsComboBox() Line 237 + 0x34 bytes   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x77 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme) + 0xa7 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(object obj) + 0x90 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(System.Windows.Forms.Control.ThreadMethodEntry tme) + 0xa2 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks() + 0xda bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control caller, System.Delegate method, object[] args, bool synchronous) + 0x365 bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate method, object[] args) + 0x50 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate method) + 0x7 bytes    
    Echo.exe!Echo.Echo.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 247 + 0x19 bytes    C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x13 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x64 bytes 
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x1b8 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x16c bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x61 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(System.Windows.Forms.Form form) + 0x33 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(System.Windows.Forms.IWin32Window owner) + 0x38f bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog() + 0x7 bytes 
    Echo.exe!Echo.Program.NewEcho() Line 48 + 0xa bytes C#
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x63 bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) + 0xb0 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x2c bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

I use the following code to create new terminal windows in a separate thread:

```
    public static void CreateNewEchoThread()
    {
        //// Create a new thread
        Thread  EchoThread      = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Program.NewEcho));

        // Set thread parameters
        EchoThread.IsBackground = true;
        EchoThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

        //// Start the thread
        EchoThread.Start();

        // Increment the number of open Echo forms
        Echo.NumberOfOpenWindows++;
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void NewEcho()
    {
        // Create a new Echo form window and show it as a Dialog to prevent the thread from exiting immediately.
        Echo NewEchoForm    = new Echo();
        NewEchoForm.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: There's no obvious reason for this warning from the code snippet.  You will have to post the stack trace, copy/paste the content of the Call Stack window into your question.

Comment: Just added the call stack window contents.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty bad mess.  It is induced by a threading problem.  You are displaying this form on a worker thread with ShowDialog().

Comment: Oh. Well, multi threaded GUI applications are new to me :-). So could you tell me how to achieve the effect I want in a better way? I use the main program to create a new thread for each opened terminal window. I use ShowDialog to prevent the thread from exiting immediately.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with the ShowDialog approach in a worker thread?

Comment: For starters, you don't initialize the thread correctly.  You didn't call the Thread.SetApartmentState() method to switch it to STA.  Required for any thread that displays a window.  Displaying UI on another thread is an advanced technique, best avoided because there are just way too many ways to shoot your foot.

Comment: I see. I did set the appartment state to STA as shown in the newly added code snippets. But maybe this approach is just too difficult...

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to achieve the same effect without running UIs in another thread?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to avoid the RaceOnRCW.

I replace the Clear call by a loop that removes each item one by one. Not the solution I like, but it seems to work.

I would still like to hear other ideas about how to do it, since it bothers me that I can't use the Clear function.

```
int NItems  = COMPortsComboBox.Items.Count;
for(int i = 0; i < NItems; i++)
{
    COMPortsComboBox.Items.RemoveAt(0);
}
```